# How is LED powered when PIN 2 is disconnected?

Tags: arduino-uno, button

Using the Arduino tutorial "[Button](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button)", I have noticed that if I totally disconnect Pin2 from the circuit, the LED comes on dimly.

I am trying to understand HOW this happens.  Is it simply due to being a floating ground?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);` line tells the board to set the `buttonPin` in high impedance mode.

When you disconnect the wire the state of that pin becomes unknown; usually it oscillates.
Since it is oscillating, the LED turns on and off randomly: you see it "dimly light".

The usual solution is to use a pull-up or pull-down. I suggest you to wire your buttons towards the ground, declare the pins as `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);` and invert the logic (i.e. `buttonState = !digitalRead(buttonPin);`). This way it will never oscillate again.

Comment: Sounds good!  Any idea why the tutorials all assume PULLDOWN and ask for resistors rather than coding for PULLUP?

Comment: That's because our mind thinks in a "positive" way. Button is pressed means, for the programmer's mind, a HIGH value. Since the atmega only has pullups, if you want to use it you have to connect the button towards ground, so the button pressed status is signaled by a LOW value. You just have to invert the logic, but... Personally I prefer to put buttons towards ground :P And, by the way, since you are learning I suggest you to experiment with debouncing ;)

Comment: Yep, de-bouncing was the next question and I've got that one mastered now.  I guess we all have the same questions getting started. :-)

Comment: Of course ;) That's why forums are a great way of learning if used properly. There is always someone who has already faced your problem ;)